# How to manipulate proxyaddresses attribute with get-adobject

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to export a list of contacts using get-adobject and manipulate the proxyaddresses attribute to only give me SMTP:e-mailaddress (the mail attribute). Right now with my command, I get everything including the x500 stuff which I do not want. Is this possible? Thanks.

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectClass -eq "contact"' -Properties * -SearchBase 'DC=A' | 
select name, givenName,sn,mail,displayName,cn,co,company,l,mailnickname,telephoneNumber,st,streetAddress,postalcode,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,mobile,department,title,proxyaddresses,targetaddress
```

Did a little Googling, and this seems to work well. Is there a better way of  coding?

```
Select-Object Name, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -like 'smtp:*') -join ";"}}
```

Comment: Well, you have a typo, it's not `proxyaddress` it's `proxyaddresses`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks for pointing that out. Thanks. Now to figure out if it's possible to just get the SMTP values.

Comment: If you want the primary SMTP address (the one with `SMTP` uppercase) you could just do `E = { $_.proxyAddresses -clike 'SMTP:*' }`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks! I learned something new today with -clike.

For anyone interested in my final iteration, the code is below.

`Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectClass -eq "contact"' -Properties * -SearchBase 'DC' | 
Select-Object Name,givenName,sn,mail,displayName,cn,co,company,l,mailnickname,telephoneNumber,st,streetAddress,postalcode,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,mobile,department,title,targetaddress, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -clike 'SMTP:*') -join ";"}}`

Comment: I'm glad you did  btw the `-join` I think its not needed because there should always be only one primary smtp address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the syntax displayed below is pretty ugly but I really recommend you to avoid `-Properties *` when you only need a specific set of attributes to query, by doing so your query will run faster and also it will lessen the computational cost.

As for getting **only the Primary SMTP Address** in the [`proxyAddresses` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-proxyaddresses), [PowerShell comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2) are by default case-insensitive, however they all have a case-sensitive counter-part. See [**Common Features**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#common-features) for details. In this case you can use `-clike` to filter the uppercase SMTP address (Primary Address).

```
$propsOfInterest = @(
    'name'
    'givenName'
    'sn'
    'mail'
    'displayName'
    'cn'
    'co'
    'company'
    'l'
    'mailnickname'
    'telephoneNumber'
    'st'
    'streetAddress'
    'postalcode'
    'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'
    'mobile'
    'department'
    'title'
    'proxyaddresses'
    'targetaddress'
)

Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectClass -eq "contact"' -Properties $propsOfInterest -SearchBase 'OU=SomeOU' |
    Select-Object @(
        $propsOfInterest[0]                                              # this is the first `Name`
        @{N='proxyAddresses'; E={ $_.proxyAddresses -clike 'SMTP:*' }}   # calculated property
        $propsOfInterest[1..$propsOfInterest.Count] -ne 'proxyAddresses' # the rest, excluding `proxyAddresses`
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson and rework of the script.